# SQL Use IN in the first column and returning the second

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table called 'account_products', which have a foreign key 'product_id' and also a timestamps 'created_at'.

I also have a table called 'products'. I'm trying to return all the products that has the id equal to the same 'product_id' from the 'accout_products'. BUT I also need the 'created_at' from the 'account_products', because I want to see when they were created.

So is there a way to tell the SQL something like:

```
SELECT * FROM products
WHERE id IN (
    SELECT product_id, created_at FROM account_products
)
```

but the IN clause only relate to product_id, also returning the created_at for each column of account_products?

Thanks!

Comment: You don't need the IN at all. What you appear to want can be done with an INNER JOIN. If you'd [edit] to provide your actual table schemas, some sample data, and the output you'd like to obtain from that data, someone here can probably help.

Comment: A `JOIN` operation may work for you, if `product_id` is *UNIQUE* in the `accounts_products` table. If it's not, then a JOIN has a potential to match your `id` value to *every* row from `accounts_products` that has a matching value in `product_id`, potentially producing "duplicate" rows in the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `join`:

```
SELECT p.*, ap.created_at
FROM products p JOIN
     account_products ap
     ON ap.product_id = p.id;
```

Comment: Though we should point out that if `product_id` is not unique in `account_products`, this query has potential to return duplicate rows from `products`. Contrast that to **`id IN (2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4)`** where a row with `id` value that matches a value in the list will only be returned once, no matter how many times a matching value is repeated in the `IN` list.

Comment: Thank you very much! Worked fine!